# How do I make Rack::Reloader re-load changes to haml files?

Tags: sinatra, jruby, haml, rack, compass-sass

My jruby rack sinatra compass haml app correctly reloads changes to *.rb files, but does not detect changes to *.haml files.

Is this compass doing some caching or a limitation of Rack::Reloader? Any pointers to how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your app:

```
enable :reload_templates
```

Otherwise template reloading is only enabled in development mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://github.com/rkh/sinatra-reloader